# Keyboards overlaps UITextView in UITableView. Why doesn't work scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I read a lot topics with the same problem, but no one solution does work.

Problem is common: In my UITableView I have many rows, which contain only two UITextView. When I start editing text in few last rows, keyboard overlaps my row.

I found perfect method `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`
and I think that should scroll my tableView, but nothing happened. Why? How to solve this problem?

I have code for this:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSubview:textView];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:true];
}
```

where `indexPathForSubview` is method in my own category for UITableView - it's work right and get right IndexPath.

Some information: In viewDidLoad I set these preferences

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

My application looks like:

[image: ViewController]

[image: overlapping]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can adjust your UITableView(subclass of UIScrollVIew)'s `contentInset`.

Of course,you can fix this by modify the size of `UITableViewWrapperView`,which is `UITableView`'s solution.
[image]

Comment: you means `contentOffset`? Yes, it can be work, but I think, that `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` is more fancy approach instead of having to calculate offsets

Comment: if you don't use `UITableViewController`,you will have trouble with `scrollToRowAtIndexPath `

Comment: If you don't adjust your view's frame or contentInset,last rows will be overlaped by keyboard.